# Js statements executed before external js loaded

Tags: javascript, esapi

I am using esapi for output encoding. But, its working weird.

**Code**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title> AC </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style type="text/css">
        .ac-container {
            font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
            font-size: 12px;
            table-layout: fixed;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
            border: 6px solid #BFCAFF;
            background-color: #F5F8FD;
        }
        .ac-close { color: #FF0000;float: right; cursor: pointer; }
        .ac-header { color: #0771D4; background-color: #E4EFFA; padding: 5px; font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px solid #B0D2F1; }
        .ac-search { padding: 3px 3px 0; }
        .ac-search table { background-color: #fff; border: 1px solid #BDCED5; width: 100%; }
        .ac-search-td1 { width: 18px; }
        .ac-search-td2 input { width: 100%; border: none; }
        .ac-searchico {
            float: left; height:18px; width:18px;
        }
        .ac-categories { padding: 3px 3px; float: right; width: 70%; }
        .ac-categories select {
            width: 100%;
            color: #000;
            border: 1px solid #BDCED5;
            font-size: 11px;
            padding: 2px 0;
            font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .ac-categories option { font-weight: normal; }
        .ac-cts-nm { font-weight: bold; float: left; }
        .ac-cts-mail { color: #777; }
        .ac-cts-row, .ac-cts-row-sel { padding: 5px 0; cursor: pointer; float: left; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E4DF; white-space: nowrap; }
        .ac-cts-row-sel { background-color: #FEFAD1; border-bottom: 1px solid #EBE5C3; }
        .ac-cts-nm, .ac-cts-mail {
            float: left; padding: 0; margin: 0; margin-left: 3px;
            color: #737373;
        }
        .ac-cts-mail { clear: both; font-size: 11px; margin-left: 21px; color: #9E9E9E; }
        .ac-cts-row em, .ac-cts-row-sel em, .ac-selectall em, .ac-selectall-check em {
            clear: both; font-size: 11px; margin-left: 21px; color: #9E9E9E;
            float:left; display: block; width: 16px; height: 16px; cursor: pointer;
            margin-left: 2px;
        }
        .ac-cts-row-sel em, .ac-selectall-check em { background-position: -22px -139px; }
        .ac-button { padding: 5px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; }
        .ac-firstico, .ac-Dfirstico, .ac-lastico, .ac-Dlastico, .ac-previco, .ac-Dprevico, .ac-nextico, .ac-Dnextico {
            width: 20px; height: 16px; cursor: pointer; margin-right: 3px;
        }
        .ac-Dfirstico { background-position: -4px -90px; }
        .ac-previco { background-position: -70px -114px; }
        .ac-Dprevico { background-position: -28px -90px; }
        .ac-nextico { background-position: -43px -90px; }
        .ac-Dnextico { background-position: -1px -114px; }
        .ac-lastico { background-position: -67px -90px; }
        .ac-Dlastico { background-position: -25px -114px; }
        .ac-navigation {
            background-color: #F5F8FD;
            border: 1px solid #CEE1F0; border-left: none; border-right: none;
            color:#9E9E9E; font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;
            padding:2px;
            text-align:center;
        }
        .ac-nav-page {
            display:inline;
            margin:0 5px;
            vertical-align:super;
        }
        .ac-navigation select { font-size:10px; border: 1px solid #BDCED5; }
        .ac-selectall, .ac-selectall-check { width: 25%; overflow: hidden; color: #000; font-weight: normal; font-size: 11px; padding: 1px 0 4px; float: left;margin-top:3px;padding:3px 0; }
        .ac-selectall div, .ac-selectall-check div { margin-top: 1px; white-space: nowrap;cursor: default; }
        .ac-nocts {
            padding: 5px;color: #aaa;text-align: center;font-weight: bold;
        }
        .ac-loading {
            background-color:#0568B2;
            color:#FFFFFF;
            font-weight:bold;
            height:15px;
            left:40%;
            padding:4px 10px;
            position:absolute;
            top:35%;
            z-index:2001;
            display: none;
        }
        .ac-button input, .ac-button input:hover {
            background-color:#74A1EC;
            border:1px outset #5983EE;
            color:#FFFFFF;
            font-weight:bold;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
    <table class="ac-container" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td class="ac-header">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="ac-loading" id="ac-loading">
                </div>
                <div class="ac-search">
                    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="ac-search-td1">
                                <span class="ac-searchico"></span>
                            </td>
                            <td class="ac-search-td2">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
               </div>
                <div class="ac-selectall" id="ac-selectall">
                    <em class="ac-uncheck"  onclick="AC.selectAll(this.parentNode);"></em>
                </div>
                <div class="ac-cts-container" id="ac-cts-container">
                </div>
               </td>
            </tr>
    </table>
    <script>
    //Adding dummy var to ignore esapi dependency error.
    var ESAPI_Standard_en_US = {
    };
    <script src="/esapi/esapi-compressed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/esapi/Base.esapi.properties.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script>
       // Initialize the api
         org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This statement "org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.initialize()" is called before the external js is loaded. So, I got "org" is undefined.

I checked chrome and firefox, got same problem in both browsers.  Is this normal behaviour?. I hope, external js is loading synchronously.

This page was embedded in a other page using iframe.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

**Javascript**
You have to wait calling that function until the DOM is loaded.
In pure js you can do that like this:

```
if (window.addEventListener) // W3C standard
{
  window.addEventListener('load', fn, false);
} 
else if (window.attachEvent) // Microsoft
{
  window.attachEvent('onload', fn);
}

function fn(){
    org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.initialize();
}
```

More information about the js version: [pure JavaScript equivalent to jQuery's $.ready() how to call a function when the page/dom is ready for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the)

**Jquery**
But it's easier to use jquery because it has fallbacks buildin. In jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.initialize();
});
```

More information about the jquery version: [pure JavaScript equivalent to jQuery's $.ready() how to call a function when the page/dom is ready for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the)

Comment: This page is included in an iframe. `window.onload or window.addEventListener` is not working.

Comment: So the object is in that iframe? Than use `document.getElementById("yourFrame").contentWindow.org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.initialize();` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page)

Comment: Sorry, I think I confused you. 

Ex: 

MyPage -> a.html is embedded in some x page. 

<iframe src="a.html"></iframe>

The problem is in my page(a.html).

Answer (score 1):

You should execute that line inside a [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload) handler.

`window.onload` is a global event fired by the browser after the document and related resources (including external scripts) are loaded.